# iOS how to manage photos

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image, tableview

I'm creating an iOS app that works with photos.

I have built apps that do similar things on Android, and know of some of the pains that images can bring with regard to storage and memory management.

Here are my questions:

- How do I save a picture that I've taken & where do I save it to (is it sensible to save it with core data somehow?)?
- How do I load a picture from wherever I've saved it to?
- For a tableview with images, do I need some form of lazy loading (you do on Android), if so, can anybody recommend a tutorial or library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How do I save a picture that I've taken & where do I save it to (is it sensible to save it with core data somehow?)?

Use the system imagepicker/taker `UIImagePickerController` and no dont store images in CoreData. As a general rule store them in the system photo library. Store the Asset Library URL as a reference.

Images can be stored in your App documents folder also.

- How do I load a picture from wherever I've saved it to?

Use the API in the `AssetsLibrary` framework to retrieve pictures from the system store.

- For a tableview with images, do I need some form of lazy loading (you do on Android), if so, can anybody recommend a tutorial or library?

No. Lazy loading is done for free by your `UITableViewController` implementation. There are a 1001 great UITableView tutorials on the web.